# Google Sheets - Two way sync from "Master" to "Trip 1", Trip 2" etc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

@Tanaike very kindly provided this modified code which works perfectly, so that when I add a unique number in the range "A2:A" on the "Master" sheet it update the range "A4:A" on all the other sheets "Trip 1", "Trip 2", etc.

I would also like the reverse to happen,  so that when I delete one of the unique numbers in "A2:A" on the "Master" sheet then it will delete the same unique number in "A4:A" on each of the sheets "Trip 1", "Trip 2", etc.

If someone could provide some help that would be so very much appreciated.

```
function updateSheet() {
  Array.prototype.showDif = function (array) {
    let that = this;
    return array.filter(function (r) {
      return !that.some(function (x) {
        return r.join() === x.join();
      })
    })
  }

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  let sourceValues = ss.getSheetByName("Master").getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String);
  const sheetNames = [ "Trip 1", "Trip 2", "Trip 3", "Trip 4", "Trip 5", "Trip 6", "Trip 7", "Trip 8", "Trip 9", "Trip 10"];
  sheetNames.forEach(name => {
    let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    if (!targetSheet) return;
    let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange("A4:A");
    let targetValues = targetRange.getValues().filter(String)
    let diff = targetValues.showDif(sourceValues)
    targetRange.clearContent();
    targetValues = (diff && diff.length) ? targetValues.concat(diff) : targetValues;
    targetSheet.getRange(4, 1, targetValues.length, targetValues[0].length).setValues(targetValues)
  });
}
```

Comment: For each sheet, get the range, set the value you just changed.  It will do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy your column 'A' after any changes:

```
function copy_data() {
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh    = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data  = sh.getRange('A2:A').getValues();
  var names = ["Trip 1", "Trip 2", "Trip 3"];

  for (var name of names) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    if (!sheet) continue;
    sheet.getRange('A4:A').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(4, 1, data.length).setValues(data);
  }
}
```

Just in case, here is the function that updated columns (adds new values, and removes removed ones) on other sheets and keeps the order of elements in the destination columns:

```
function update_column_keep_order() {
  var ss       = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh       = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var src_data = sh.getRange(`A2:A${sh.getLastRow()}`).getValues().flat();
  var names    = ["Trip 1", "Trip 2", "Trip 3"];

  for (var name of names) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    if (!sheet) continue;

    var dest_data = sheet.getRange(`A4:A${sheet.getLastRow()}`).getValues().flat();
    var map = new Map(dest_data.map(x => [''+x,x]));

    // add all values from source range to destination range
    for (var key of src_data) if (key !='') map.set(''+key, key); 

    // clear the values in destination range that absent in source range
    var diffs = src_data.dif(dest_data);
    for (var dif of diffs) map.set('' + dif, '');
    var updated_dest_data = Array.from(map.values()).map(x => [x]);

    // put the values in destinaion range on the sheet
    sheet.getRange('A4:A').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(4, 1, updated_dest_data.length).setValues(updated_dest_data);
  }
}

// based on Tanaike's solution
Array.prototype.dif = function (array) {
  return array.filter(r => !this.some(x => r === x))
}
```

Values in column 'A' must be unique.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and providing the above solutions.

I tried using your 'function update_column_keep_order()'  but it does not appear to be working as intended.

When I add a unique number to colA in the "Master" sheet and run the script it does not add the unique number to colA in the "Trip 1" sheet. It has added colA from the "Summary" sheet to the "Trip 1" sheet.

The following is a link to the Google sheet file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zDasQ_uaWv56nkL7_UE5_EqUcbHti4VOPtiuUPTc8B8/edit?usp=sharing

Again many thanks @Yuri Khristich for your help.

Comment: Since I had no your real sheet I've used just first sheet as 'Master'. You had to change it of course. It's just one line: `var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];` to `var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Master');`